# Accessing Android views on nested layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I have trouble accessing Views from a layout that is included in another layout. 
Please take a look at this picture:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3473245/layout_includes.png

How do I access the 4 text views programmatically?
Its probably something really simple that I'm missing.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you maybe show the XML instead? Normally you would use `findViewById`, this can be done on a sub-view as well.

Comment: I think you can use getChild() in your case.

Comment: @tidbeck, I have pasted the xml here: http://pastebin.com/GyAWsBMy

Comment: @Yury I have tried it, but the ViewGroup seems to return null all the time.

Comment: @fusion44 so how have you tried to access it? `View layout = findViewById(R.id.activityBaseLangView); TextView tv = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.languageHeader);`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do as follows:

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include android:id="@+id/item_base_lang" layout="@layout/dictionary_list_item" />
    <include android:id="@+id/item_learn_lang" layout="@layout/dictionary_list_item" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**dictionary_list_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dictionary_list_item_text_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dictionary_list_item_text_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To set the text programmatically:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_base_lang).findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_item_text_header)).setText("item_base_lang_header");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_base_lang).findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_item_text_content)).setText("item_base_lang_content");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_learn_lang).findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_item_text_header)).setText("item_learn_lang_header");
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.item_learn_lang).findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_item_text_content)).setText("item_learn_lang_content");
```

[This Android wiki page](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html) shows how to use reusable UI components with XML layouts, but it doesn't show how to access nested reusable components from code.

Although it is fairly straightforward, it might be not so clear for those who are pretty new to Android Views.

Comment: thanks! I think this is what I needed. Sorry for the late answer all

Comment: This code is giving me a NullPointerException...after debugging, I realized that the problem was when the included file was being referenced (in the first "findViewById"). Do you know how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The following two lines should help you get the languageHeader of both includes. You can do the same for languageText

> findViewByid(R.id.activityBaseLangView).findViewById(R.id.languageHeader)
>   findViewByid(R.id.activityLearnLangView).findViewById(R.id.languageHeader)